# Are the words Bank (money) and Bank (river) related?

Tags: meaning, etymology, language-evolution, sociolinguistics

In one of our class discussions about the origins of the word Bank (Money), a guy guessed that maybe it comes from the Bank (the land alongside a river) since the sand gets deposited there, as an equivalent to Bank being a money depositing place. It felt right, except Bank comes from Banque, a Latin word for table, as that's how the financial transactions used to happen, over a table.

Now, what I want to know is could it be that Bank and Bank are related? One coming from the other? If so, which one came first?

Comment: Sounds like folk etymology to me. The origins are different. https://www.etymonline.com/word/bank

Comment: They are two different words but with common roots. That's why they are called _cognates_.

Comment: It's been a while since I studied Latin, but I don't think that "banque" is a Latin word (at least not classical), and a search through some online dictionaries seems to confirm that. Where did you find that spelling?

Comment: @Lambie In your Etymonline link, please click on "see bank (n.2)". You'll see that the origins are actually similar (Proto-Germanic *bankon).

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Sorry, but I don't read it that way at all.

Comment: Common origin does not mean they are the same.

Answer (score 4):

[Per Etymonline:](https://www.etymonline.com/word/bank)

1. "Bank" as in the side of a river comes ultimately from the  Proto-Germanic root **bankon,* meaning "slope."
2. "Bank" as in the financial institution ultimately comes from the related Proto-Germanic root **bankiz-,* "shelf." This root led to *banca* in Old Italian and *banque* in Old French, meaning "table"; the word came to be used in English to mean "money-dealer's counter or shop," from which the modern sense is derived.

Since the the roots **bankon* and **bankiz-* are cognates, the two are ultimately related. But neither of the modern English senses came from the other,  nor did either come from Latin.